# Print all points in an infinite grid of n dimensions

Tags: c#

I can not have infinite points stored in the computer, but what I mean by that is the max value of Int64 (long).

I could use a nested loop, but that would take an eternity to go to the next line, so I found another way.

All the points whose x and y values add upto n are on a diagonal.

> (0,0) - 0

> (1,0),(0,1) - 1

> (2,0),(1,1),(0,2) - 2

(all of these are diagonals)

So we could iterate through all values of n, from 0 to max value of long, that would give us all the points on all the diagonals.

So I wrote the code to do this.

```
        public void Main()
        {
            for(long i = 0; i < Int64.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                long[] a = new long[(i + 1)];
                long[] b = new long[(i + 1)];
                
                for(long j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    a[j] = j;
                    b[j] = (i - a[j]);
                }
                f(a,b);
            }
        }
        
        public void f(long[] a, long[] b)
        {
            string toPrint = "";
            
            for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                toPrint += "(" + a[i] + "," + b[i] + "),";
            }
            Console.Write(toPrint + "\n\n");
        }
```

It does the job for a grid of 2 dimensions, but I want it to work for n dimensions, the same idea applies

Comment: so what exactly is your _question?_

Comment: I wrote code for a 2 dimensional grid. How do I do that same thing for n dimensional grid.

Comment: Use recursion. Also, see my previous sentence.